# What's wrong with my profane filter in Java?

Tags: java, filter

In this program, "cat", "dog", and "llama" are considered profane and needs to be filtered out of a sentence. Any version of those three words in CAPS("cAT"), extra letters("lLlama") needs to be considered as well. My program currently only reads one word at a time nor will it read capital/lowercase letters. How can I add this?

One run through:

```
Enter a line to be checked for profanity:DoG CaT LlAmA |


Your input line 
 does not contain cat
 does not contain dog
 does not contain llama
This line would not be considered profane.
```

This is wrong, the input does contain the words and is considered profane.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProfaneFilter
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a line to be checked for profanity: ");
    String sentence;
    sentence = keyboard.next();

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Your input line ");

    sentence = keyboard.nextLine();
    sentence.equalsIgnoreCase(sentence);

    if (sentence.equals("cat") && sentence.equals("dog") && sentence.equals("llama"))
        System.out.print("contains cat" + "\n" + "contains dog" + "\n" + "contains llama" + "\n" + "This line would be considered profane.");
    else if (!sentence.equals("cat") && !sentence.equals("dog") && !sentence.equals("llama"));
        System.out.println(" does not contain cat" + "\n" + " does not contain dog" + "\n" + " does not contain llama" + "\n" + "This line would not be considered profane.");

    if (sentence.equals("cat"))
        System.out.println("contains cat");

    else if (sentence.equals("dog"))
        System.out.println("contains dog");

    else if (sentence.equals("llama"))
        System.out.println("contains llama");
    }
}
```

I know I'm probably missing some important code to get the output I'm looking for, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: You're using `String.equals` instead of `contains`. `sentence.equalsIgnoreCase(sentence);` doesn't do anything; you want something like `sentence = sentence.toLowerCase(sentence);`

Answer (score 0):

You could get the output you need, using the contains instead of the equals, as the equals looks for an exact match. Also if you could cast the input string to the lower case, it may help.

Please try running the code below and see if it works. Also feel free to replace the if else with switch case if you feel its more readable.

```
package details;

import java.util.Scanner;

import org.omg.Messaging.SyncScopeHelper;

public class ProfaneFilter
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a line to be checked for profanity: ");
String sentence;
sentence = keyboard.next();

System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("Your input line ");

sentence = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();

StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
if(sentence.contains("cat")){
    stringBuffer.append("The sentence contains cat \n");
}else{
    stringBuffer.append("The sentence doesnt contains cat \n");
}
if(sentence.contains("dog")){
    stringBuffer.append("The sentence contains dog \n");
}else{
    stringBuffer.append("The sentence doesnt contains dog \n");
}
if(sentence.contains("llama")){
    stringBuffer.append("The sentence contains llama \n");
}else{
    stringBuffer.append("The sentence doesnt contains llama \n");
}
System.out.println("stringBuffer is "+stringBuffer.toString());
```

}

}

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input! Though this didn't work exactly how I needed, it sure did help me understand new ways to approach this! Hint: I'm still a beginner :P.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write it. This would use an array of your profane words, and iterate across them to see if the sentence contains them.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PF {
    public PF() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a line to be checked for profanity: ");
        String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nYour input line: " + sentence);

        String [] prof = new String []{"cat", "dog", "llama"};
        for (String s : prof)
        {
            if (sentence.toLowerCase().contains(s))
                System.out.println("The sentence contains " + s);
            else 
                System.out.println("The sentence does not contain " + s);
        }       
    }
    public static void main(String...banana) { new PF();}
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input! Though this didn't work exactly how I needed, it sure did help me understand new ways to approach this!